# Spring REST: Create a custom response for special return value

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I would like to add a cross cutting strategy, that converts certain return types of Spring `@RestController` methods to another response entity.

Given, that I have an interface

```
interface AsyncResult<T> {
  public CompletableFuture<T> getResult();
}
```

I would like to write

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public AsyncResult getAsyncResult() { return ... }
```

and create the actual response in some kind of strategy, e.g.

```
public ResponseEntity convert(AsyncResult result) { 
  if(result.getResult().isDone()) {
    return new ResponseEntity(result.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
  } else {
    // headers e.g. AsyncResult: true, Poll-Location: /result/result-id
    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPT, headers);
  }
}
```

I guess that this is possible by registering something similar to an `@ExceptionHandler` ?

Comment: you can directly send the MyCustomResponse using @ResponseBody annotation to upstream.

Comment: @Vaibs This is not what I want to do. I will edit the question to give you a better picture of my needs

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that the answer is to implement a `org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`